# Is there any difference between the two methods provided to short-circuit the pipeline?

Tags: asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core middleware, there are two ways to short-circuit:

By not calling `next.Invoke()`...

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    // Do something
    // Don't call await next.Invoke();
});
```

And by calling `app.Run` instead of `app.Use` like so...

```
app.Run(async (context) =>
{
    // Do something
});
```

But I can't really see a difference in either of them, so why is there a choice?

From testing, both stop the pipeline from executing middleware that is next in the chain, but both also provide the previous middleware a chance to modify the response.

The documentation explains:

> Middleware added to the pipeline before the middleware that terminates
> further processing still processes code after their next.Invoke
> statements.

It also states the following in relation to the app.Run method:

> Run delegates don't receive a next parameter. The first Run delegate
> is always terminal and terminates the pipeline. Run is a convention.
> Some middleware components may expose Run[Middleware] methods that run
> at the end of the pipeline

So is the choice simply down to a case of convention, or is there more to it?

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that the `Run()` definitely short-circuits and may generate a response while `Use()` performs work on the request and can forward to the next delegate or short-circuits

There is another `Map()` which Reroute the request.

if you use `Use()`

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    //do some work
    //expected to await next.Invoke() otherwise it shortcircuit the response
});
```

You can have multiple `Use()`, but you can have only one `Run()` and it must be the last one because it definitely short-circuits, So if you aim to extend the pipeline  using `Use()` is the better option than `Run()`

Comment: You can have more than one Run call, but only one is ever executed. You can perform work on the request and the response when calling Run too. Run indicates it will definitely short-circuit, but you can definitely short-circuit with Use if you want to, other than not forwarding to the next delegate, which you would expect to be the case since this is definitely short-circuiting, I don't really see a difference, it is almost as if this convention is to indicate the intent to developers and that's about it.

Comment: Yes you can have multiple Run(), but what's the point? The first one will short-circuit and never reach another one unless you put it under if statement.
Yes you can perform the work on Run() , It's not against my post, but it's the last middleware and it limits the scenarios that you can use

Comment: What's the point of having Run when the last item in the pipeline will end the pipeline execution anyway? There is no exception thrown if you have multiple Run calls, it seems so stupid to me, hence why I was asking if there was a difference between Run and Use that just short circuits.